# How to place an object next to another, and horizontally center and right-align it?

Tags: html, css

### What is happening

[image]

### What I want to happen

[image]

I want the `icon-x-circle` to be horizontally centered and **on the same line** as "Rename" but be right-aligned (probably `30px` away from the right end of the `header`). If someone could let me know how to do that it would be greatly appreciated!

*Something to note:*
[image]

The `icon-x-circle` itself is not centered. For some reason Fontastic icons seem to add extra space at the bottom. So this is another reason why I'm struggling to horizontally center `icon-x-circle`.

### My Code

*HTML*

```
<div id="popup-rename" class="overlay">
        <div class="popup">
            <header>
                <h1>Rename</h1>
                <a class="close icon-x-circle" href="#"></a>
            </header>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="student-name student-rect">
                    <h1>Student Name</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="save-button center-children">
                    <a class="save icon-check-circle" href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*CSS*

```
header{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

header h1 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 300; /*100, 200*/
}

.icon-x-circle{
    color: #E1E1E1;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  background: white;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.popup header{
    padding: 20px;
}

.close, .save{
    transition: all 200ms;
}

.icon-x-circle:hover {
  color: #B6B6B6;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14ongm/49abesy2/)

Comment: Have you figured out a way to eliminate that extra bottom spacing fontastic adds? It's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

One method for aligning elements is to use `position`: `absolute;`:

```
.icon-x-circle {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        width: 300px;
        border: 3px solid #73AD21;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning and put the button wherever you want.

first, make header a relative container

```
header{
   position: relative;
}
```

Then you can make the button absolute

```
header a{
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 10px
}
```

You can mess with `right` and `top` to move the button wherever.

https://jsfiddle.net/49abesy2/1/